# как добавить второй псевдо элемент ::after и :before?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Мне надо добавить оформление к div.

сверху и снизу я уже добавил элементы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код псевдо элементов [scss]:

```
.content {
        background-color: seashell;
        width: 20vw;
        height: 20vw;
        margin-top: 4vw;
        margin-bottom: 4vw;
        border: 0.3vw solid #53b796;
        border-radius: 1vw;
        position: relative;
        &:after{
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 20vw;
          left: 0.7vw;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left: 9vw solid transparent;
          border-right: 9vw solid transparent;
          border-top: 3vw solid #53b796;
        }
        &:before{
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: -3vw;
          left: 0.7vw;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left: 9vw solid transparent;
          border-right: 9vw solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 3vw solid #53b796;
        }
      }
```

Как мне добавить такие же элементы ещё слева и справа ?
И как я могу закруглить эти треугольники ? border-radius не работает.

Дополнение:
Слева как есть, справа как должно быть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: seashell;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0.3vw solid #53b796;
  border-radius: 1vw;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  perspective: 30px;
}

.outer:after,
.outer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #53b796;
  border: 2px solid #53b796;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer:before {
  right: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotateY(-8deg);
  border-radius: 20% 0 0 20%;
}

.outer:after {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotateY(8deg);
  border-radius: 0 20% 20% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробовал все варианты. которые здесь предложили.
В интернете нашёл самый ленивый и быстрый способ. Он со своими недостатками конечно, но для простых целей подойдёт.

Свойство clip-path создает ограниченную область, которая определяет какая часть элемента должна быть видимой.

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
```

На результат применения этого свойства можно посмотреть по ссылке
[clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете добавить более 1 `:before` и `:after` для элемента. Если надо больше - добавляйте обертки из `div'ов`

UPDATE: Вместо треугольников можете использовать прямугольники и проиграться с [`border-radius`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius)

```
  <div style="border-radius: 40px 10px" class="radius">
   border-radius: 40px 10px;
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А как мне закруглить и обрезать можно треугольники ? Я в дополнение к вопросу прикрепил картинку как есть и как должно быть.